# Подсчитать количество прохождений цикла

Tags: c++

Вот есть часть кода для пар pair(string, int) make_heap(v.begin(),v.end(),comparator())

Как подсчтюитать сколько раз он пройдет?

Comment: Struct comparator
{
Bool operator() (const P &i, const P &j)
{
return i.second>j.second;
}
};

Comment: Добавить в код счетчик...

Comment: А в какое его место?

Comment: У меня просто строчка make_heap(v.begin(),v.end(),comparator()), а потом вывод всех элементов кучи и все. Пихал счетчик в comparator, но тогда программа вообще не работала

Comment: Вас интересует сам вызов `make_heap`? Или в него, или рядом, при вызове.

Comment: какого цикла хоть? подозреваю, что это очередная [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710)

Comment: Компаратор должен иметь счетчик

Answer (score 1):

Может как то так

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Comparator
{
private:
    static std::size_t count;

public:
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r)
    {
        ++count;
        return l > r;
    }

    static std::size_t GetCount() {return count;}
    static void Reset() {count = 0;}
};

std::size_t Comparator::count = 0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> vector;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        vector.push_back(i);

    Comparator comparator;
    std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), comparator);

    std::cout << "count: " << Comparator::GetCount();
    Comparator::Reset();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это просто. Добавляем в компаратор счетчик(не важно по какому критерию он сравнивает)

Допустим вваш компаратор сравнивает пары по их по второму аргументу:

```
using P = std::pair<string, int>;
struct Comparator {
    static int k;
    bool operator ()(const P& p1, const P& p2)
    {
        ++k;
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    }
};
int Comparator::k = 0;
```

И дальше тоже просто:

```
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), Comparator());
cout <<Comparator::k;
```